# pexpect - expecting pattern

Tags: python, pexpect

How can I work with pexpect when the "expect" is not fixed:

Example: `+DTMF: X`, where `X` could be any integer from 0 to 9, such as `+DTMF: 1`.

I tried this but not success:

```
self.child.expect('+DTMF:', timeout=1)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

pexpect uses regular expressions,
you can do this:

```
self.child.expect('\+DTMF: [0-9]', timeout=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue recently. Since the numbers at the end were important for me I found out that you could parse them by running those two lines.

```
child.expect('+DTFM: ')
value = child.read(1)
```

I assumed that you only had one digit, but you can specify the number of expected character on the child.read function.

Otherwise using regex will yield a more exact expect statement.